# How to delete an endpoint only if exists

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm creating a script to automatically configure 2 databases for mirroring, using [this how to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suhde/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-database-mirroring-between-sql-server-instances-in-a-workgroup) but I want to make sure there is no end point or master key already created so I would like to first do some clean up as:

```
DROP ENDPOINT End_Mirroring;
DROP CERTIFICATE PRIM_cert;
DROP MASTER KEY
```

But how can I do these drops only if they already exist?(i need this to avoid my script to exit with error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.tcp_endpoints WHERE name = 'End_Mirroring')
DROP ENDPOINT End_Mirroring;
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.certificates WHERE name = 'PRIM_cert' )
DROP CERTIFICATE PRIM_cert;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE [name] LIKE '%DatabaseMasterKey%')
DROP MASTER KEY";
```

OK, found it :)

Comment: FYI, almost everything that can be CREATEd, DROPped or ALTERed has a system view to test